# Where should I run the function if I only want it to execute once

Tags: php, html, laravel, database, laravel-livewire

```
@foreach($data as $row)
@php
App\Http\Livewire\Teamusers::edit($row->id,$row->user_id,$row->team_id);
@endphp
{{--call edit() function from teamusers component--}}
<td class="p-3 px-5"><input type="text"  wire:model = "username"  class="bg-transparent"></td>
<td class="p-3 px-5"><input type="text" wire:model = "email" value="{{$row->email}}" class="bg-transparent" ></td>
<td class="p-3 px-5">
   <select value="team" wire:model = "team" class="bg-transparent" >
      @if($row->name == 'Fieldwork')
      <option value="1" selected>Fieldwork</option>
      <option value="2">Labs</option>
      @endif
      @if($row->name == 'Labs')
      <option value="1" >Fieldwork</option>
      <option value="2" selected>Labs</option>
      @endif
   </select>
</td>
<td class="p-3 px-5">
   <select value="role" class="bg-transparent" wire:model = "role">
      @if($row->role == 'management')
      <option value="management" selected>management</option>
      <option value="general">general</option>
      @endif
      @if($row->role == 'general')
      <option value="management" >management</option>
      <option value="general" selected>general</option>
      @endif
   </select>
</td>
<td class="p-3 px-5 flex justify-end">
   <button type="button" wire:click="edit({{ $row->id }},{{ $row->user_id }})" class="mr-3 text-sm bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white py-1 px-2 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">Save</button>
   <button type="button" class="text-sm bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white py-1 px-2 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">Delete</button>
</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

edit.php

```
public function edit($id,$user_id,$team_id)
    {

        $user = Teamuser::findOrFail($id);
        $real = User::findOrFail($user_id);
        $third = Team::findOrFail($team_id);
        $this->username = $real->name;
        $this->email = $real->email;
        $this->team = $third->name;
        $this->role = $user->role;


    }
```

The edit() function binds the data to the columns in for each loop. But as a result, it keeps refreshing everytime.
[image]

What should i do if i still want the data binding but without the refreshing?

Comment: did you use jquery? it will help you to achieve your functionality.

Comment: jquery could solve the issue easily

Comment: Yeah jquery is probably more suitable for stuff like this, thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to use .defer on your livewire model data binding ? This will makes your component not real time and will only submit your data when you click on save button.

Does it help you ?

Comment: I did another pop-out page to edit all the data's, ill try using .defer if I encounter similar problem in the future. Thanks for the answer!